# global keyword in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, global

I'm studying python, and getting struggle with the global keyword within `vscode`. So far the code is working, but the `vscode` linter is raising an error, and I would like to understand why

I've tried using the global keyword, and the code works fine even though I got a linter error. I try using a local variable and didn't get any error

```
def whatIs ():
    global myvalue
    myvalue +=10
    print("myvalue: {}".format(myvalue))

myvalue=10

whatIs()

print("myvalue: {}".format(myvalue))
```

The linter points to the `myvalue` in the function :

> Undefined variable 'myvalue' pylint(undefined-variable)

But the output is what I expect.

```
myvalue: 20
myvalue: 20
```

It's like `vscode` doesn't like the global keyword

Comment: The linter is checking the code from the top. When it checks the `whatIs` method, it doesn't know that a global variable `myvalue` __will__ be defined later on.

Comment: Why should you use `global` is the first question? You can pass argument and return the result in the simplest readable way.

Comment: `pylint` takes automatic exception to `global`. According to its rule you are never right to use it. That is only sort of true, and not all of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving this line

```
myvalue=10
```

before the definition of WhatIs function.

```
myvalue=10

def whatIs ():
    global myvalue
    myvalue +=10
    print("myvalue: {}".format(myvalue))

whatIs()

print("myvalue: {}".format(myvalue))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's considered bad practice to use Global variables in python.  A simple fix is to save the function call as a variable like so.

```
def whatIs(myvalue):
    myvalue +=10
    print(myvalue)
    return myvalue

result = whatIs(10)
print(result)
```